# How to loop through arguments in Bash ($1 $2 $3 and so forth)?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have the following code snippet

```
for num
do
   echo $num
done
```

But I don't understand why it works! How come does Bash know to loop through my params $1, $2, $3, $... using my personal taste of "num" variable???

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a feature of bash:

```
for num; do ...
```

is a shorthand for

```
for num in "$@"; do ...
```

The documentation is at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs

Comment: For the record, this is not bash-specific feature. It was present all the way back to original Bourne shell. ( Learned so from old System V book )